# Social logins with Masked domain

Tags: laravel-5.1, google-signin, laravel-socialite

I use sub-domain for all clients like **client.example.com** and then i masked their domain over it. i have added social logins Google, Facebook and LinkedIn.

Facebook and LinkedIn Seems to be working but the issue with Google Login its just showing blank white page when i hit the URL for login.

is it possible to use social logins for masked domain?

because other two are working fine and google is not throwing any error so could not figure out the solution.

Project is in Laravel-5.1 and i use Socialite

Any help would be great

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

step 1
     Install Pod File for `pod 'Google/SignIn'`
step 2
For below code to Add `AppDelegate`

AppDelegate.swift
    import UIKit
    import Google
    import GoogleSignIn
    import FacebookCore

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(String(describing: configureError))")

    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

print("Google+ url scheme")
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

 }

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

print("Google+ url scheme")
            let sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String
            let annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
    import UIKit
    import GoogleSignIn
    import FacebookCore
    import FacebookLogin

    class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var rememberMeSegment: UISwitch!
        @IBOutlet weak var appSignInButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var googleSignInButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var facebookSignInButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var appSignUpButton: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        self.profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImage.frame.height/2
        self.profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }
        @IBAction func googleSignIn(sender: UIButton) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"]
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().shouldFetchBasicProfile = true
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

        if (error == nil) {

            print("Name : \(user.profile.name!)")
            print("Email : \(user.profile.email!)")

            if let email = user.profile.email {
                self.emailText.text = email
            }

            if(user.profile.hasImage){
                print("Profile Image : \(user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 100))")

                self.profileImage.downloadedFrom(link: user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 100).absoluteString)

            } else {
                print("Profile Image : Profile image not available")
            }

            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()

        } else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

 - extension String {
           func hexStringToUIColor () -> UIColor {
               var cString:String = self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()


        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
        }

        if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
            return UIColor.gray
        }

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
}

extension UIAlertController {
    convenience init(title: String, message: String) {
        self.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK action"), style: .default, handler: nil)
        addAction(action)
    }
}
```